# engine troubles upgrading forked app to rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

I have forked [pka's mapfish-rails-sample-app](https://github.com/pka/mapfish-rails-sample-app) and I am trying to upgrade it from rails 3.0 to rails 3.2, but I'm having engine troubles.  Specifically, the [rails 3.2 Release Notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#what-to-update-in-your-engines) indicates that I should replace the contents of script/rails to include:

```
ENGINE_PATH = File.expand_path('../../lib/your_engine_name/engine', __FILE__)
```

However, the lib directory does not contain any engines that I can tell (it contains a ruby file geonames.rb, and an empty "tasks" directory).  (In addition, the vendor/plugins directory is also empty, in case that is relevant.)

**Do I need to install an engine? If so, which one?  If not, what should I do about the ENGINE_PATH?**

My ruby version is 1.9.3p194, rails -v is 3.2.0

FYI, I first tried to NOT upgrade to 3.2, but I had troubles with bundler being at version 1.0.0, which was incompatible with my installed rubygems, and it was unclear which version of rubygems would be compatible with bundler 1.0.0, where rubygems seemed to want bundler at 1.1.4.  Eventually I thought it would be easier to upgrade it all to Rails 3.2, to keep my entire setup consistent...

I first tried leaving the setting of ENGINE_PATH commented out, but when I ran `rails server`, I of course got the error `uninitialized constant ENGINE_PATH (NameError)`.

I tried setting ENGINE_PATH as:

```
ENGINE_PATH = File.expand_path('../../lib', __FILE__)
```

but I got the error `cannot load such file -- c:/Cedric/workspace/mapfish-rails-sample-app/lib (LoadError)`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, please let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Regards,
Cedric

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using any "Engines" (which you're probably not) you can remove all of the lines from ENGINE_ROOT down in the script/rails file.

A fresh rails 3.2 install generates a script/rails file that looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 3 gems installed from the root of your application.

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```